# Core Data Migration: How should i change the data type from bool to int in next version

Tags: ios, core-data-migration

My concerns:

1. The app is in App Store with data model version 3.
2. What i have used & worked till now is Light Weight migration.
3. Now i added version 4 with new entities & Attributes.
4. But i need to just change data type of one attribute which was BOOL in version 3 to Int in Version 4.

Query:
So how should i address this? Will light weight migration still works or need to go for manual. Please suggest on this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

didn't try but since BOOL and int are both internally saved as NSNumber's, lightweight migrations should work.

Comment: Thanks @Cyril, Its sound good will test & mark your answer as accepted once get successful result. Thanks

Comment: I have just created a test project reproducing your test case and my assumption was good, lightweight migration works.